# How to add column names to histogram when using par() function in r

Tags: r, histogram

I would like to plot all histogram in my data frame. One way I tried was hist.data.frame(df) which gave me very small pictures of each. Then I tried this code:

```
library(datasets)
data(iris)
X<-iris[,0:3]
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
histout=apply(X,2,hist)
```

This time, each picture is big enough but all of them have a title like Histogram NewX[,i]. When I have so many variables, this is very unclear. Is there anyway that I can add column name to each graph? Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `apply` on a dataframe; it's meant for arrays.  Use `lapply` or `sapply` or `vapply`.  But if you want nice titles, you probably want to apply some function to the names in the dataframe.  So try something like `sapply(names(combined), function(name) hist(combined[[name]], main = name))`.

Comment: @user2554330 Hi! Thanks for your reply. I just made an example using Iris dataset. Can you show me how to do it? Thanks!  I tried lappy, but it gave me this error message: Error in match.fun(FUN): '2' is not a function, character or symbol
Traceback:

Comment: @user2554330 I got what you mean now:). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use `lapply` and feed extra arguments to the `hist` function in there (`main`, `xlab`, etc.). You could also use a loop.

For instance,

```
library(datasets)
data(iris)
X<-iris[,0:3]
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
lapply(names(X), function(k) hist(X[[k]], main=k))
```

[image]

Edit: Sorry, this is essentially the same answer as given in comments. I had not seen it.

Comment: After I see your answer, I fully understood the comment made by user2554330, yes your answer is highly appreciated.